# What verb form should I use after "and/or"? "are" or "is"?

Tags: sentence-construction, singular-vs-plural

The sentence is the next:

> Item can't be represented in the graphic because its value on X **and/or** Y **aren't** defined.

After "**X and/or Y**" should I use "**aren't**" or "**isn't**"?

And if I use "**X or Y, or both**", what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, contracting sentences can have undesirable side effects. If you want to use contraction, and to be proper entirely, you should use:

> Item can't be represented in the graphic because its **value(s)** on X **and/or** Y **aren't/isn't** defined.

So, as you can see, it is a total mess.

You may want to rephrase it like:

> **The** item cannot he represented in the graphic because its coordinates are not both defined.

or:

> **The** item cannot he represented in the graphic because at least one of its coordinates is not defined.

Please note the extra "the" at the beginning of the sentence.

---

If you want to use the sentence as an error message, you might try:

> The object cannot be represented graphically. Please define all coordinates...

However, this is not very useful, and you should be explicit which coordinates are missing, e.g.:

> The object cannot be represented graphically. Missing coordinate(s): (X, Y, Z)...

where the program decides which letters are displayed (X, Y, Z), according to the missing information.

Comment: The second phrase you said is the most accurate and it solves my problem. I dont really like the fact of using "at least" in a error message but I can't find a better solution. Thank you so much for the answer! :)

Comment: You should have mentioned that the sentence is to be used as an error message. That is a game changer, actually.

Comment: Well, sorry about that. Its a 'backlog' message, and the original message is: "The content with name: <CONTENT_NAME> and ID: <ID> can't be represented in the graphic because its value on originPointX and/or originPointY aren't defined.".

Comment: I provided in the answer a "template" which you can use more generically in your situation.

Comment: The problem is I dont know when one or both coordinates are missing. I just know when one or both are missing. Yeah thats a problem, but I can't fix that problem. So, your first "template" means that ALL cordinates are missing and that could be a false positive. And I cant use the second one because I cant specify which one are missing. But never mind, the phrase "The item cannot he represented in the graphic because at least one of its coordinates is not defined." fits well enough, as I said is a 'backlog' message and is not very important. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: You choose what suits best for you. You are welcome.